# Create a user for use with Azure Sync

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

Rather than use the built in admin for Azure Sync, I'd like to create a separate user and logon for it. Is this at all possible? What permissions would the user need, if so? I tried adding a user to the DataSync_Admin role but even on the admin account it says I lack permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following permissions should be provided to that account.

Synchronization operations require the following permissions:

- EXECUTE permissions on all the stored procedures that Sync Framework uses to read and write to metadata tables and base tables.
- SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE permissions for metadata tables and any base tables that will be updated during a synchronization session.

When you provision SQL Server databases that use SqlSyncProvider, be aware of the following permissions requirements for provisioning:

- CREATE TABLE permissions to enable creation of the metadata tables: scope_info, scope_config, scope_parameters, and scope_templates, and the tracking tables that are created for each base table.
- ALTER TABLE to add triggers to the base tables.
- CREATE PROCEDURE permissions to create the procedures that Sync Framework requires.
- SELECT and INSERT permissions for scope_info, scope_config, scope_parameters, and scope_templates tables.
- SELECT permissions for base tables.

Please refer to [this Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-best-practices?view=azuresql#database-accounts-with-least-required-privileges) for more permissions required for deprovision and other tasks.